# PDF Rendering library

Tags: c++, pdf, directx, windows-8, windows-runtime

I working on a Metro Style application that need to render PDF documents (only viewing). I am looking for a library to render a .pdf document on the screen, preferably one I can include in my "commercial" app (pdf viewing is only a side functionality). Unfortunately, Windows 8 (atleast in the Dev Preview) does not have native PDF support :(
Any suggestions for a library? I am writing my app in C++/Cx.

Minor addition: Third-party options shall not use APIs that are not allowed in Metro Style apps. :-/

Alternatively, I need a PDF parser and I will try to create my own Direct2D renderer (might work ok for simple PDFs).

Comment: I can recommend [this](https://www.idealsoftware.com/en/pdf-library/report-engine.html) commercial library. It has a viewer included.

Comment: @nabulke is the library winrt compatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinRT - view and edit PDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577007/winrt-view-and-edit-pdf)

Comment: Аpitron.PDF.Rasterizer also WinRT-compatible and could be used in Windows Store apps and Windows Phone 8 applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 8.1 (Blue) will include PDF viwer and editor APIs (WinRT based). Therefore, this seems to be the easiest solution for my scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Ghostscript, or MuPDF, I'm sure there are others. Both will require programming on your part. Both are available under commercial licences as well as GPL.

Comment: And if you want to use it commercially without giving out your sources you will have to contact them. At least mupdf is GPL.

Comment: I guess the point is that this question says: '...preferably one I can include in my "commercial" app'.

Comment: Both are available under commercial licences as well. GPL doesn't preclude use in a commercial application, though its harder, many people prefer to use commercial licenced software. So I stand by both my comments :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of [development libraries on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PDF_software#Development_libraries) that lists the different license types and languages alongside. Quite useful, though probably not exhaustive.

At the time of writing, ones that much your requirements of C++, Windows with a commercial license are:

- [Adobe PDF Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_PDF_Library)
- [LEADTOOLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEAD_Technologies)
- [PDFTron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDFTron_Systems)